# Could not load file or assembly when connect to database in UWP

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp, azure-sql-database

I am working on Universal Windows Applications, in one of my project I want to connect with the Azure sql database, for that I was added the below code Using `SqlConenction` class.

```
try
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    string query = null;
    //DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
    connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxx_db;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
    connection.Open();
    // Converts image file into byte[]
    // byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(App.m_photoStorageFile.Path);
    query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Delivery_Analytics.xxxxxx] (Name,MobileNumber,CompanyName,DeliveryAddress,Image,Timestamp)" +
                    "Values ('" + nameTxtBx.Text + "','" + mobileNumTxtBx.Text + "','" + comapanyNameTxtBx.Text + "','" + deliveryAddress + "','" + pictureTxtBx.Text + "','" + dateTime + "')";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

But when I am trying to open the `SqlConnection` I got the below exception.

> Could not load file or assembly `System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have seen this error when your assembly versions do not match from library to library. What .net assembly version are each of your class libraries?

Comment: I used >=4.5 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) is not for Windows Runtime/UWP, that's why you got this exception.

We can not access SQL Server Database from UWP app directly, we have to create an Service layer to access the database.

The right way is to create a web service and our app can consume it to retrieve data.

For example, you can choose [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/).